# What is the difference between sublimation and instantaneous fusion+vaporisation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, phase, sublimation

Sublimation is defined by the [IUPAC](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/S06069) as *The direct transition of a solid to a vapour without passing through a liquid phase*.

A sublimation equilibrium can occur in two sets of conditions:

- at a temperature-pressure set given by the phase diagram of the pure substance. This is only possible if the pressure is lower than that of the triple point.
  E.g. sublimation of $\ce{CO2}$ at -78.5 °C and 1 bar:

[image: CO2 phase diagram]

- at any other temperature-pressure set, provided the temperature is lower than the melting point and the pressure is higher than the vapour pressure of the solid. This is possible even at a pressure higher than that of the triple point, if the gas phase in the system is not the pure substance (such as a system with air). E.g. sublimation of $\ce{I2}$ at 100 °C and 1 bar:

[image]

However, what happens in a case far from equilibrium, such as when applying a red-hot metal rod on an ice cube? (i.e. an object with a very high thermal conductivity and at a temperature much higher than the boiling point of the substance it is applied to). Some will consider this a sublimation, others will describe it as an instantaneous fusion+vaporisation (my issue is with the use of the term "instantaneous").

For this situation, I have coined several propositions, both on the physical process and on the terminology:

1. The temperature gradient is so great, the conditions are so far from equilibrium, that the substance will not go through a liquid phase: it is sublimation.
2. Since the atmospheric pressure is higher than the pressure of the triple point, the system will go through a liquid phase, however short-lived it is: it is fusion followed by vaporisation.
3. From a molecular point of view, the molecules do received enough energy to melt, then to vaporise; however, the state of a phase is not defined at the molecular level: considering a liquid phase in these conditions does not make sense. Considering a "fusion+vaporisation" does not make more sense than talking about sublimation. From a thermochemical point of view, the presence of a liquid phase cannot be evidenced experimentally since $\Delta H_{sublimation} = \Delta H_{fusion} + \Delta H_{vaporisation}$, enthalpy being a state variable.
4. Even though the presence of a liquid phase cannot be evidenced (or if considering a liquid phase does not make sense), the temperature at which the process takes place is higher than the melting point: it is, by convention, not considered sublimation.
5. Even though, from a thermodynamics point of view, the system should go through a liquid phase, the two processes ("sublimation" and "fusion+vaporisation") are in competition. The two phenomena could occur simultaneously. The idea, here, is similar to phenomena such as supercooling and superheating of liquids. The solid-to-liquid transformation, while thermodynamically favoured, could be kinetically unfavoured in such extreme conditions. I would consider this a similar process to MALDI: using a laser to "desorb" (as per the acronym, but is the process really different from sublimation?) a solid which would, upon slower heating, decompose instead. If sublimation does not occur in the case of the metal rod on ice, would a laser (e.g. IR) be able to do it? What would be the difference between the two?

Which of these propositions would you consider the most appropriate? Do you have another view of the process? Regarding the terminology: when would you use "sublimation" in such cases?

Comment: Close to the metal rod you will have a very large temperature and pressure gradient that might result in rupture of the solid or even an explosion, depending on conditions. Furthest from the rod and adjacent the solid you will have a layer of water. You will not see sublimation.

Comment: @BuckThorn "or even an explosion": because of the rapid formation of a gas. Does that not correspond to the definition of sublimation?

Comment: Sublimation is strictly speaking a first-order phase transition involving direct conversion from solid to gas. In your experiment you go through the liquid, if for no other reason that the pressure is so high. The phase diagram wins. But it is "almost" sublimation. The dangling molecules at the interface however won't care what you call the process.

Comment: However this does make me think of laser-induced cavitation: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0301932220305425

Comment: I agree that the molecules do not care what we call the process. I'm also interested in the terminology. So... Would you agree with my proposition #3? Or are for #2?

Comment: I suspect either case might be valid depending on experimental circumstances. Sorry about the slippery answer. Surface energy would become important if there is partial fragmentation ("explosion"?) of the solid. Imagine small chunks of solid flying off, temporarily in a low pressure setting. You are trying to describe a highly non-equilibrium system so time is a variable and the appropriate description will obviously change with time.